# What does `ls /` do?

Tags: ls

Running the `ls /` command some files are coming out;

What are those files?

They are not even directories.

Output of `ls /`:

```
bin dev boot etc cdrom media mnt home lib lib64 proc root
```

Comment: I'm assuming you're assuming those should be the same on each system, but they're not; please [edit] your question and add the output of `ls -l /` by pasting it inside the editor, selecting it and clicking the **{ }** button at the top, because no one knows what you have inside `/`

Comment: I'm not sure why @kos asked you to add the output of `ls -l /`!? `ls /` simply lists all the files and directories in the top-most level of your filesystem. Running `nautilus / &` will do the same with a GUI.

Comment: @lucideer Despite the title, the question seems to be about the origin of the files in `/`; in a fresh installation there are no regular files in `/`, so someone / something must have place them.

Comment: I am not getting you @kos,my actual question was what does "ls / "command do

Comment: Ok, but then I don't get what you're missing; judging from your first statement you seem aware of the fact that `ls` lists files and folders; if you run `ls /`, it will list the files and the folders in `/`. The actual question was "which files are they", which I don't know how else I should interpret. Please clarify exactly what you're not understanding.

Comment: @kos I assumed the general thrust of his question was "What is `/`" as Ubuntu's general UI has recently tended toward abstracting away filesystem structure (as OSX and Windows have done).

Comment: @Knight `bin dev boot etc cdrom media mnt lib lib64 proc root` are all folders on your filesystem that make up the Linux OS and various apps. Then the `home` folder is where all of your own personal files are stored. Try `ls /home`.

Comment: @lucideer I think you're right; the question's body was a little misleading though.

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/unix-file-system.htm - Linux is still UNIX, thanks $DEITY....

Comment: @lucideer -Yes that is what I was asking .Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ls /` lists the contents of the root directory.  (Elsewhere I wrote an explanation of the various meanings of the word `root`, which you can read [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/233589/command-explanation-mkdir-p-root-ssh/233642#233642).)

The files that are showing up in the output are indeed directories, as you can easily verify by running `ls -p /`.  The `-p` flag will cause `ls` to append a slash to every directory listed, so you can differentiate them from files that are listed.

The source of the confusion seems to be that you don't understand what is called the *Linux Filesystem Hierarchy*.  There are specific directories in specific locations, each with a specific purpose.  For example, `/etc` (pronounced "slash et-see") contains configuration files; you can think of the name `etc` as an acronym for "editable text configuration."

Each of the directories in the output of `ls /` have a specific purpose.  The *full* reference material explaining this can be found [here](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/).  For a decent primer on the Linux Filesystem Hierarchy, written for those familiar with Windows, try [here](http://lug.oregonstate.edu/blog/fshguide/).

Even more fundamental than the purpose of all these directories is the concept that ALL files and directories on Linux are part of a single directory "tree".  Do a google image search for "directory tree" if the term "tree" seems confusing.  Unlike Windows where you have various drives (the C: drive, the D: drive and so on), in Linux, mounted drives are tied in to the rest of the directory tree at a "mount point", which is just another directory.